# Lots of noise after repitching recorded file using raw audio data and simpleaudio

Tags: python, audio

I have written a very basic script to repitch an audio file, which I import using [simpleaudio](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleaudio.html). I am not worried about preserving audio speed; all I need is a simple pitch-shift.

What I am doing is resampling the audio using linear interpolation, and from what I've read, this should be enough. For example, you can see here that the pitch of the audio is shifted, but it retains a very similar shape:

[image: sound graph]

The blue line is the initial waveform, the orange is the pitch-shifted waveform. It all looks exactly how I would expect.

So far so good. However, when playing it back through simpleaudio's interface, the shifted wave is really really noisy. Interestingly though, **this doesn't happen if I shift by an integer ratio**.

See the code below for my implementation (there's not much, I promise):

```py
import math
import simpleaudio as sa
import struct

def data_to_samples(data):
    samples = []
    for i in range(0, len(data) - 2, 2):
        smpl = struct.unpack(">h", data[i:i+2])
        samples.append(smpl[0])
    return samples

def samples_to_data(samples):
    data = bytearray()
    for sample in samples:
        for b in struct.pack(">h", sample):
            data.append(b)
    return bytes(data)

def interpolate(a, b, t):
    # Linear interpolation is good enough
    return a + (b - a) * t

def change_pitch(data, rate):
    LIMIT = (1 << 15) - 1

    samples = data_to_samples(data)
    index = 0
    finished = []
    while index < len(samples) - 1:
        i = int(index);          
        frac = index - i;
        s1 = samples[i];
        s2 = samples[i + 1];

        val = int(interpolate(s1, s2, frac))
        val = max(-LIMIT, min(LIMIT, val))

        finished.append(val)
        index += rate

    return samples_to_data(finished)


wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("a4.wav")
data = wave_obj.audio_data

play_obj = sa.play_buffer(data, 1, 2, 44100)
play_obj.wait_done()

changed = change_pitch(data, 1.1)   # < 1.1 is the pitch shift ratio
play_obj = sa.play_buffer(changed, 1, 2, 44100)
play_obj.wait_done()
```

`data_to_samples` take the bytes read by simpleaudio and unpack them into 16-bit samples, in a list. `samples_to_data` does the opposite. I had problems with them in the past, but I think they are working completely fine now.

In playback, `1, 2, 44100` are all the correct parameters - the audio is mono, 16-bit, and using 44100Hz sample rate.

To my eyes, everything is exactly as it should be. It even looks right when I graph it, as mentioned above.

So, what's going wrong? I'm really stuck, and any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wav files are little-endian, not big-endian.

`struct` should be using `"<h"`, not `">h"`.

This wasn't a problem when using integer pitch-shift ratios, because there wasn't actually any interpolation happening in that case - it was just selecting every nth sample. And since each conversion function was the reverse of the other, it was like nothing had every changed.

But as soon as you start to interpolate, you get problems, because you're now working with 'reversed' data in a non-reversed way.

Anyway, my algorithm now works perfectly.